# How to hide this .wpnotif_admin_conf .wpnotif_sts_logo (class) from WordPress Admin Area

Tags: wordpress

I have tried this CSS, But not working, still showing.

```
.wpnotif_admin_conf .wpnotif_sts_logo {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Now what I can use to hide this Class from the Admin Area?

Answer (score 0):

Use a comma if these are 2 classes.

```
.wpnotif_admin_conf, .wpnotif_sts_logo {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: I missed that comma here but I used that in the site. But that is not working. See the image https://i.imgur.com/jFnxJyK.jpg I want to hide the Red Marked.

Comment: Could you please try this?
 .wp-admin .wpnotif_sts_logo {
    display: none;
}

Comment: Still, it's not working. Maybe it will not work with CSS, Need to use JS or PHP. If you are interested, I can give you access to the site, so you can practice.

Comment: Sure, I can take a look.

Comment: How can we contact? Can you please share your Contact Information like WhatsApp? Also, I can share the plugin file so you can test it. Let me know which one you prefer?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where you are adding the CSS. As this is a backend page, adding the CSS on style.css or additional CSS in Customizer won't work.

You need to add a custom CSS for the admin and mention the CSS there. Check [admin_enqueue_scripts](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_enqueue_scripts/).